# I can't move a button inside a frame layout

Tags: android, button

I have tried to move the button using graphical interface and         android:layout_alignParentLeft in XML file, anyway it does not work. My Android Studio version is 2.2.3. Have you ever had this problem?

[image]

Comment: please show your xml code..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) or other simlilar layout as parent container because [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) just draw the views one over another plus you should check the properties section to see the `attibute` properties that you can apply on your layout.

[To read further about ViewGroups and it's sub-types with their behaviours](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

Comment: @MMManuel i am glad that i could help , happy coding :)

Comment: Then why should we even use FrameLayout and not just always RelativeLayout? FrameLayout seems to be useless in most cases. Only usefull for webView which needs the whole area.

Comment: @Black it's useful for fragment transition at run time and when you have multiple view one over another and only wants to show the one at top, or like you want to display a description view on the top of a image etc..

Answer (score 4):

If you forced to use FrameLayout(e.g in Toolbar or so) and you have only one element(or small amount) to operate with(button) you can use             `android:layout_gravity=""` attribute to align element in the FrameLayout.

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

If you have have few elements in your layout, you can: 1) Change FrameLayout to RelativeLayout or 2)Wrap all items into Relative layout and set parameters to `match_parent`

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```