# Can't change position of elements in webview

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, webview, constraints

I developed a simple webview app which is working fine.

Now I have to add a back button.

[image]

I added it as a child of "FrameLayout". I can change the size, but I can't change the position of the button, it just sits at the top left... This seems to be the case for any element, I just tried it with ImageView and I have the same problems with it.

I also tried to use "RelativeLayout" instead of "FrameLayout" as adviced in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41395794/4684797), but it makes no difference

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I changed to "ConstraintLayout" now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use XML.

Add this to your XML:

```
<Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
```

Or replace `<RelativeLayout>` with `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321448/differences-between-constraintlayout-and-relativelayout) why it works.