# Can't move a button in design view of android app

Tags: android

I have the following view, and I want to move the buttons in the layout of the view, but when I drag the button, it doesn't move to its new place.

How to fix that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
                style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/dummy_button" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </FrameLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41395794/14969444) answer, you can't use the graphical interface when your root layout is a FrameLayout. You can try with RelativeLayout or just do it in code.